# Given an array A[], determine the minimum value of expression: min( abs( a[ i ] - x ) , abs( a[ i ] - y ) )

Tags: sum, difference, absolute, minimum

Given an array A of N integers. Find two integers `x` and `y` such that the sum of the absolute difference between each array element to one of the two chosen integers is minimal.

Determine the minimum value of the expression

**`Σ(i=0 to n) min( abs(a[i] - x), abs(a[i] - y) )`**

Example 1:

- N = 4
- A = [2,3,6,7]

**Approach**

- You can choose the two integers, 3 and 7
- The required sum = |2-3| + |3-3| + |6-7| + |7-7| = 1+0+0+1 = 2

Example 2:

- N = 8
- A = [ 2, 3, 5, 8, 11, 14, 17, 996 ]

**Approach**

- You can choose the two integers, 8 and 996
- The required sum = |2-8| + |3-8| + |5-8| + |8-8| + |11-8| + |14-8| + |17-8| + |996-996| = 6+5+3+0+3+6+9+0 = 32

**Constraints**

1<=T<=100

2<=N<=5*10^3

1<=A[i]<=10^5

***The sum of N over all test cases does not exceed 5*10^3.***

**My code : **
Please help me with the optimal solution O(N) or O(NlogN)

```cpp
int minAbsDiff(vector<int> Arr, int N)
{
        // Approach: O(N^3)
        sort(Arr.begin(), Arr.end());
        int sum = INT_MAX;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            for (int j = i + 1; j < N; j++)
            {
                int tmp_sum = 0;
                for (int k = 0; k < N; k++)
                {
                    tmp_sum += min(abs(Arr[k] - Arr[i]), abs(Arr[k] - Arr[j]));
                }
                sum = min(sum, tmp_sum);
            }
        std::cout << "Sum is :" << sum << std::endl;
        return sum;
}
```

Comment: We're not just going to do your homework. Try something, and we can help you with a concrete issue you've run into. See the [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6166/109689)

Comment: I have already invested 15 hr in solving this question. However, I didn't find an optimal solution. I am able to solve this in O(N^3) time but It is not acceptable.

Comment: I know the solution of one element with a minimum absolute difference but not two elements from the array.

Comment: For a single element, it would be the median of the array. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-array-element-having-minimum-sum-of-absolute-differences-with-all-other-array-elements/?ref=rp

Comment: "I am able to solve this in O(N^3) time but It is not acceptable" That's awesome progress, you should show it off here so people have a place to start. Showing your background researhc/effort will always attract more positive attention to your question